# What does " Mozilla/5.0" in user agent string signify?

Tags: http, browser, user-agent, mozilla

I am using `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to record the user's browser and operating system in use after he logs in my website, when I `echo` this it shows me these

**Firefox**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
```

**Chrome**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19
```

**Safari**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Safari/534.50
```

**Opera**

```
Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; en) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.50
```

**IE**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
```

I'm interested to know why **Mozilla/5.0** is prefixed when I `echo` it in IE, Safari And Chrome?

Comment: Honestly? Pretty much _anything_. :)